# I can't upload application in app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, svgkit

I have an issue when uploading an application to the App Store. When I upload the application it shows the error:

[image]

I'm using SVGKit and it runs perfectly on my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the version of CocoaLumberjack (open-source logging library) bundled with SVGKit is now incompatible with Apple's rules.

First: check with CocoaLumberjack if this is a known issue.

Second: if they have a fixed version, try replacing the version that ships with SVGKit. It's a simple operation - you copy/paste the new framework source code over the top of the existing framework source code. If you have problems, ask on the SVGKit github project and someone will help you out (a few people have upgraded CocoaLumberjack in the past)